# How to host the same Vuejs app with multiple subdomains pointing to it in Docker?

Tags: laravel, docker, vue.js, multi-tenant

I have a multi-database multitenanted Laravel API, which can identify tenants by subdomain (or by token). In order to be able to issue tokens, I need to know which tenants the user is attempting to sign into. For this, I need to be able to host my Vue.js application under multiple subdomains, how do I achieve this? The backend is already handled as the package im using ( https://tenancyforlaravel.com/ ) does this out of the box for the backend, but I'm using a Vue.js frontend as opposed to Blade for my frontend.

I have a Docker image which contains:

- the multitenanted API (`backend`)
- the database cluster (`database`)
- a business frontend app (handling signups and tenant management) (`frontend`)
- the SaaS application (`app`)

I need to be able to create subdomains on the fly that allows `app` to be accessed from multiple places. Effectively I'm thinking of hosting something like `app.mybusiness.com`, and any subsequent tenants I create point to the same domain as `app.mybusiness.com` **but** retaining the subdomain e.g. tenant1 accesses `tenant1.mybusiness.com`. Locally I can do `localhost:3001` currently to access my app, but I would need something like `tenant1.localhost:3001` to also point to that - the most important thing is that I should be able to allow *everything* and the subdomain is checked through the API, rather than setting them up one by one. How can I do this locally **and** how can I do this in production? I'm thinking of hosting my app on Heroku or Vercel (or something similar) eventually for prod.

Comment: Do you want each service to have is own subdomain? Reverse proxy (NGINX) can help you. Traefik is also great choise.

Comment: #1 Do you have the backend, frontend and database in only one container? #2 Add a graphic of your current infrastructure. #3 At the end, Do you need to have a.com, b.com , c.com and in the php backend detect what web is being accesed?

Comment: @MikiBelavista no not each service to have a subdomain; there is one service (the app) I want multiple subdomains for. e.g. app.mydomain.com, tenant1.mydomain.com, tenant2.mydomain.com all point to the `app` service

Comment: @JRichardsz 1. yes all of the 4 services are in the same container 3. Yeah so based on the subdomain from the frontend, I can either send a request to `subdomain.mybusiness.com/api/*` which will all point to the `backend` service already (the app supports subdomains out of the box with no additional config required), or I can alternatively do a get request for the tenant from the frontend based on the subdomain; I just need a way to be able to effectively duplicate the `app` service under multiple subdomains